# Prevent Oracle package from being executed in production

Tags: oracle, plsql, permissions, package

I created an Oracle PL/SQL package which I want to prevent being executed in a production environment, or on a specific database, which could be dangerous. Indeed, it turns out I have admin rights and could inadvertently compile the Developement package in a production environment.

I tried checking the context in my package's body with something similar to this:

```
create or replace package body my_test_package is

    context varchar2(64);

    function get_context return varchar2 is
    begin
        -- return context: DEV or PROD
        ...
    end;

    -- list of other functions & procedures ....

    begin   
        if context = 'PROD' then
            dbms_standard.raise_application_error(-20001, 'production context, prevent execution of this package');
        end if;
end;
```

However, I know it is bad solution because the initialization time takes place **only once**, as stated by [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/packages.htm):

> The initialization part of a package plays a minor role because, unlike subprograms, a package cannot be called or passed parameters. As a result, the initialization part of a package is run only once, the first time you reference the package.

So, that means all subsequent procedure calls following the first one will be executed, even in a production environment. E.g:

```
-- production environment
begin
    my_test_package.dangerous_procedure();
exception when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('bypass context exception');
end;
my_test_package.dangerous_procedure(); ---> EXECUTED IN PROD :(
```

Is there a common idiom or a known approach to prevent a package from being executed in a particular environment? (e.g. without having to copy the same piece of code in each procedure/function of the package, to check it has the right to execute).

Thanks

Comment: If the procedures in the package should never be executed in a particular environment, why does the package need to exist in that environment?  If the package needs to exist in that environment, why does anyone need `execute` access on the package?  If you really want the package to exist in an environment you never want it to be executed in and you really want to give users permission to execute methods in the package they should never execute, each method in the package could run a `check_context` function that throws the error if the environment is one you want to avoid.

Comment: @JustinCave I thought of what you propose, e.g. the `check_context` function, but it means mass-copying the same piece of code in EVERY function/procedure in the package, right? This would not be a good approach imho. /updated my question

Comment: If you want the package to exist and you want users to have permission to execute the methods and you want the methods to do something different in production, you'd need to change the code of all the public methods.  If you don't like calling a `check_context` function in each public method, you're on a recent version of Oracle, and you're willing to relax the constraint that permissions are identical across environments, you could potentially use code-based access control and only grant the package permission to do whatever dangerous tasks in certain environments.  But that seems circuitous

Comment: I don't see the issue as a problem is with procedures but with "could inadvertently compile the Development package in a production environment"; how about a major change to a delete statement? Anyway for procedures 2 options come to mind. Special User in Prod, and could "inadvertently compile the Development package in a production environment"; how about an updated version of a delete or truncate? Anyway for procedures 2 approaches come to mind: A special user in production and   [conditional compilation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#BABIHIHF)

Comment: The first in production environment set up a specific user with admin privileges and remove those from ALL other users. Do not create this user in development. As far as conditional compilation just put conditional statement that unless a specific external condition exists it will not compile. Use either or perhaps both.

Answer (score 1):

It is common to have this requirement in the opposite direction: i.e., you have processes that run in PROD that you do not want to run (or not run the same way) in DEV.  For example, you might have a program that generates a file and FTPs it to a trading partner.  You wouldn't want that to run in DEV by accident after a clone from PROD.

We build the implementation for requirements into our code, rather than relying on database-level things like dropping objects in certain environments (or constantly re-installing things in DEV instances after a clone) and/or revoking security.  By building things into our code, we have the flexibility not just to *prevent* something from running in one instance or another, but to let it run but run differently (e.g., generate the FTP file, but send it to a test server instead of the trading partner).

To do this, we have a piece of data that has the name of the production database (we use an application feature called "profile values" for this, but you can just put it in a custom table).

Then, in any environment-sensitive process:

```
BEGIN
  l_db_name := xxcust_common_utils_pkg.get_production_dbname;  -- you write this function based on where you put the production database name...
  IF sys_context('USERENV','DB_NAME') = l_db_name THEN
    ... act like you want to in production
  ELSE
    ... act like you want to in non-production
  END IF;
END;
```

It's very simple, but unfortunately does require coding.